# Change a tab to a semicolon?

Tags: shell

I have a file that needs a semicolon delimiter after the first field, which is 4 or 5 characters in length.  I tried using sed (modified a sed script I found) and it was an epic fail...it inserted semicolons between every character.  I just need to add a semicolon to the end of the first field.

Here is some example text:

```
2A19    kRSUnicode  205.8
2FA1A   kRSUnicode  206.2
2FA1B   kRSUnicode  207.5
```

And the output I'm hoping for:

```
2A19;   kRSUnicode  205.8
2FA1A;  kRSUnicode  206.2
2FA1B;  kRSUnicode  207.5
```

Anyone know how to do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabs and spaces are known as whitespace. This will replace the first character of whitespace with a semicolon:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]/;/'
# or
sed 's/[[:space:]]/; /' # preserves the space char.
```

This will replace the first instance of all whitespace with a semicolon:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/;/'
```

This will replace all instances of whitespace with a semicolon:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/;/g'
# or
tr '\t ' ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

If you don't care about anything after the semi-colon, this is even ***more*** trivial with `awk`

```
$ awk '$0=$1";"' infile
2A19;
2FA1A;
2FA1B;
```

---

This is trivial with `awk`

```
awk '$1=$1";"' OFS='\t' infile
```

#### Output

```
$ awk '$1=$1";"' OFS='\t' infile
2A19;   kRSUnicode      205.8
2FA1A;  kRSUnicode      206.2
2FA1B;  kRSUnicode      207.5
```

Comment: Based on the OP's comment below, "I'll be dropping the rest of the line so what comes after the semicolon doesn't matter." You can finish the whole task with: awk '$1=$1";" {print $1}' OFS='\t' infile

Answer (score 0):

It really helps to include sample data and output in your question, but based on what you have said, the following will work

```
# replace the first space in a line with a semicolon.
printf    "sample data1, data2 data3\n" \
| sed 's/ /;/'
```

Produces the output

```
sample;data1, data2 data3
```

you can process whatever file  you have with

```
sed 's/ /;/' file > newFile
```

Or if your using Linux with GNU sed

```
sed -i 's/ /;/' file
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was adding in some code samples at your suggestion and noticed that it's not a space at all -- it's a TAB char!  So your kindly offered sed script didn't work; however, you made me hopeful that this isn't particularly hard.  I just need to add a semicolon to the first item.  I'll be dropping the rest of the line so what comes after the semicolon doesn't matter.  Just the first part.

Comment: @user1149499, this is obviously an important requirement -- please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update:

```
sed 's/\(\s\+\)/;\1/' file
```

Based on the Input Data, you can match the first tab and add `;` before it.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
2A19    kRSUnicode  205.8
2FA1A   kRSUnicode  206.2
2FA1B   kRSUnicode  207.5

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed 's/\(\s\+\)/;\1/' file
2A19;    kRSUnicode  205.8
2FA1A;   kRSUnicode  206.2
2FA1B;   kRSUnicode  207.5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop below [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) command for every line

`echo "abcde I am a good boy" |sed -e 's/ /:/'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shell only method:
It wasn't 100% clear on whether the first delimiter space was a tab or a variable number of spaces, so I just used echo to squeeze them all into 1 space here

```
FILE="tmpfile"
OUTPUT=""
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do
    LINE=`echo $LINE`
OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${LINE/ /; }
"
done < "${FILE}"
echo "${OUTPUT}" > "${FILE}"
```

or if it is in fact a single tab, simply:

```
...
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${LINE/    /; }
"
done < "${FILE}"
...
```